# Classpath with network drive to run Java program

Tags: java, applescript, classpath, network-drive

I have a bunch of jars in a shared (Windows) network drive. I would like to refer those `jars` using `java -classpath /network/drive/path/* myClass`. I will be running this command from an `applescript` so I have tried something like below-

```
 do shell script "java -classpath smb://user:pass@server/shared/jars/* myClass"
```

but it doesn't seem to work, is there a way to do it rather than having a whole bunch of jar files in the local machine or inside the `Application` package?

The above works on a Windows `batch` script like

```
java -classpath S:\shared\jars\* myClass
```

Comment: Seems kind of silly to do that imo.  Just bundle the jars with the application and remove them from the shared drive.  You are essentially binding your application to a network connection.

Comment: You can only do in Java what the OS allows. If you can CD to the directory, you can use it.

Comment: Actually, the reason for using a shared pool of `jars` is because a lot of them are in-house custom apps and are constantly changing to accomodate new requirements.

Comment: Can't you mount the shared directory as a proper path in the filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Windows example is not really a fair comparison, as there you have clearly mapped a drive letter to the network path which you then use with your Java command.  The equivalent on Mac OS is to mount a network volume, which you can do through Finder -> Go -> Connect to server, or via AppleScript using the `mount volume` command.  Either way, if you mount `smb://user:pass@server/shared` you can then access its contents under the path `/Volumes/shared`:

```
do shell script "java -classpath /Volumes/shared/jars/\\* myClass"
```